# Unity - How add source on runtime to ParentConstraint

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, constraints

How can I add a GameObject (or Transform ->object.transform) to a parent constraint component at runtime?
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animations.ParentConstraint.html

In the inspector, Unity shows the Parent Control component takes a Transform as Source as shown in the image below. In code, `ParentConstraint.AddSource` requires a ConstraintSource object. But trying to do this in the code it complains the constraintSource can't be a Transform

!https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YOdCQj6MWKgZkgfkaw0DDV5SlI_Apd35

```
ConstraintSource mySource = m_RealObjOnPlane.transform;//error - can't convert Transform to Animations.ConstraintSource

Xaxis.GetComponent<ParentConstraint>().AddSource(mySource);//AddSource only takes a ConstraintSource
```

Expected that I can change the source of parent controls at runtime

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ConstraintSource constraintSource;
void Start()
{
    var go = new GameObject("Source");

    var cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    var parentConstraint = cube.AddComponent<ParentConstraint>();
    constraintSource.sourceTransform = go.transform;
    parentConstraint.AddSource(constraintSource);
}
```

So in your case, it should be something like this

```
mySource.sourceTransform = m_RealObjOnPlane.transform;
```

Comment: I can certainly add the correct source with this answer, thank you @buxter . Unfortunately I'm trying to simulate a parent-child relationship with this feature but the "child" does not move when the "parent" moves

Comment: Unity allocates a weight of 0 to the source at runtime, so in my case I had to add constraintSource.weight=1; see Sources weight at bottom of spec https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-ParentConstraint.html

Comment: Just to be clear, it's not Unity that's assigning a value of 0 to constraintSource.weight, but rather the default initialization of a float member of a struct (ConstraintSource is a struct).  In the code above, since constraintSource.weight is never assigned a value it just keeps its default value of 0f.